# Move google logo when bottomSheet minimises and maximises

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to move google logo in maps when the bottom sheet maximises and minimises. I am using bottomSheetBehaviour inside a coordinator layout.
This behaviour can be seen in Google maps app.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to the problem:

I added **app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"** to the mapview and added **app:layout_insetEdge="bottom"** to the Nested Scroll view of bottom sheet.